# javascript jquery deferred not working with worker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, worker

I have the following javascript code:

```
var promises = [];

    // Entries contains an unknown amount of items. For the sake of this
    // sample, it has five.
$.each(entries, function() {
    promises.push(doProcessing());
});

return $.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
    alert('success');
}).fail(function() {
    alert('failed');
});
```

If my `doProcessing` function is:

```
function doProcessing() {
    var def = $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Request completed');
        def.resolve();
    },2000);

    return def.promise();
} // End of doProcessing
```

I get my `Request completed` log five times, followed by a 'success' alert. If I change my doProcessing method to be:

```
function doProcessing() {
    var def = $.Deferred();

    // Worker has a message
    myWorker.onmessage = function(event) {
      console.log('Worker finished');
      def.resolve();
      console.log(def);
    };

    myWorker.postMessage({action:'doSomething'});

    return def.promise();
} // End of doProcessing
```

Where my worker is now doing some processing and resolving the deferred, then I no longer get my `success` alert. I DO get five `Worker finished` messages, and my def object is also logged out.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You've got a single worker? How do you distinguish the 5 different finish messages? Or does the first message resolve all 5 deferreds?

Comment: can you post worker code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I DO get five Worker finished messages, and my def object is also logged out.

But it's the same `def` object. By

> ```
>  myWorker.onmessage = function(event) {
>      …
>  }
> ```

you are overwriting the `.onmessage` property, and only the last listener will be called - by all 5 events. Instead, do something like

```
worker.messages = 0;
function doProcessing() {
    var def = $.Deferred(),
        id = worker.messages++;

    // Worker has a message
    myWorker.addEventListener("message", function l(event) {
        if (event.data.id != id) return; // It's not for us!
        console.log('Worker '+id+' finished');
        def.resolve(event.data);
        worker.removeEventListener(l);
    });

    myWorker.postMessage({action:'doSomething', id:id});

    return def.promise();
}
```

and adapt the worker code so that it does pass the `id` back.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I've updated my code and this resolved the issue.